# Use JSON output from Flickr to display images from search

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, flickr

I need to display the images on my site from a JSON request.

I have the JSON:

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=6a970fbb976a06193676f88ef2722cc8&text=sampletext&sort=relevance&privacy_filter=1&safe_search=1&per_page=5&page=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

And I have the format I need to put the photo URL in:
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

But I don't know how I would loop through that, I found some examples similar, but I am still having trouble seeing what I need.

I am using JavaScript/jQuery to pull the info.

I figure I would have this in a loop.

```
CurrentPhotoUrl = 'https://farm'+CurrentPhotoFarm+'.staticflickr.com/'+CurrentPhotoServer+'/'+CurrentPhotoId+'_'+CurrentPhotoSecret+'_n.jpg'
```

But each of those variables would need to be populated with an value from the element. I would need to loop through all 5 elements that are in the JSON.

Any help on how to create this loop would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
var n = JSON.parse(x)  //x is the json returned from the url.
var _s = n.photos.photo;
for(var z = 0 ; z < n.photos.photo.length ; z++)
{
   var CurrentPhotoUrl = 'https://farm'+_s[z]['farm']+'.staticflickr.com/'+_s[z]['server']+'/'+_s[z]['id']+'_'+_s[z]['secret']+'_n.jpg'
   console.log(CurrentPhotoUrl);  
}
```

Edit ( With actual JQUERY AJAX call )

```
    var n ='';
 $.ajax({url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=6a970fbb976a06193676f88ef2722cc8&text=sampletext&sort=relevance&privacy_filter=1&safe_search=1&per_page=5&page=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", success: function(result){

        console.log(result);
        n = result;
        var _s = n.photos.photo;
        for(var z = 0 ; z < n.photos.photo.length ; z++)
        {
           var CurrentPhotoUrl = 'https://farm'+_s[z]['farm']+'.staticflickr.com/'+_s[z]['server']+'/'+_s[z]['id']+'_'+_s[z]['secret']+'_n.jpg'
           console.log(CurrentPhotoUrl);  
        }  


    }});
```

Output:

https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7198/6847644027_ed69abc879_n.jpg
https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2517/3905485164_84cb437a29_n.jpg
https://farm1.staticflickr.com/292/32625991395_58d1f16cea_n.jpg
https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8181/7909857670_a64e1dd2b2_n.jpg
https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8143/7682898986_ec78701508_n.jpg

Comment: JSON.parse is not necessary. The json in the url is not stringified json and for these purposes can be worked with as is.

Comment: @Zader, what would you suggest I do to bring in the data then?

Comment: @Varun, I got the following error:
VM421:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @shellwe Can you post your code here, coz i used the json directly and it works

Comment: @shellwe Please check the edit and post your code because I am unable to find any errors.

Comment: It was this line "var n = JSON.parse(x)". It is entirely possible I did something wrong when testing it. I tried your AJAX jQuery call and it worked wonderfully. I posted another solution below that someone suggested and that worked too. I need to see which way is better/efficient or if it even matters.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes your json data will not change. So inside a .js file, set your json to a variable.

```
var json = <paste json here>;
// the photos are inside an array, so use forEach to iterate through them
json.photos.photo.forEach((photoObj) => {
    // the photo will render via an img dom node
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    var farmId = photoObj.farm;
    // you can fill out the rest of the variables ${} in the url
    // using the farm-id as an example
    img.src = `https://farm${farmId}.staticflickr.com/${serverId}/${id}_${secret}.jpg`
    // add the image to the dom
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Inside your html file that contains a basic html template, load this javascript file via a script tag, or just paste it inside a script tag.

If you want to *get* the json from the web page and assuming you have the jquery script loaded...

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: <flicker_url_for_json>,
        success: (response) => {
            // iterate through json here
        },
        error: (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: My JSON will change depending on what I am searching for. I would assume I need jQuery.ParseJSON or jQuery.GetJSON to pull it down and then I can try that, and I guess that was the majority of my question.
I am interested in what you did there, is ${serverId} something special that it knows to grab the JSON? I am used to JS like "hello "+firstName+", how are you today"

Comment: ``${variable}`` is _string interpolation_ in javascript. Now to get the json from that web page, it's easiest for you to use jQuery's ajax. I'll edit my answer to show this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That part I see quite a bit when googling it. My question more lied in how to pull "owner", or "secret", or "title" from the JSON and construct my own string with the pieces. But I some others helped, thank you for your time!

Comment: Yea you index into the json as you would another js object. either through bracket `json["key"]` or dot `json.key` notation. Where key is "owner", "secret", etc.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it was that easy. I got that part taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but its is something someone suggested and it worked.

```
const requestURL = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=6a970fbb976a06193676f88ef2722cc8&text=sampletext&sort=relevance&privacy_filter=1&safe_search=1&per_page=5&page=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1'

$.ajax(requestURL)
  .done(function (data) {
    data.photos.photo.forEach(function (currentPhoto) {

      console.log('https://farm'+currentPhoto.farm+'.staticflickr.com/'+currentPhoto.server+'/'+currentPhoto.id+'_'+currentPhoto.secret+'_n.jpg')

    })
  })
```

Varun's solution worked for me as well. I don't know which one is better but I thought I would post this as well since it looks like they were done fairly differently.

Comment: Accepted your own answer?

Comment: I don't really know SO etiquette. I just chose to use what a colleague sent to me and I posted it here as an option for people to use. It was less lines of code so it seamed more efficient but after more reading I hear that forEach isn't very efficient in JS. I switched the answer checkmark back to yours.